# Need to open every url in the loop

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I'm using Selenium and Python. I'm trying to make a script that gets the info on the page, it gets specific elements and some attributes, so it opens the given URL each time the element is processed in the list.

The problem is that it stucks on the fisrt URL, and code stops, dont break, dont show any message, anyghing...

Please, help me

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    # need the below imports to work with Explicit wait
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    #profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'E:\\Users\\Luan\\Music\\redmp3')
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('audio/mpeg'))
    profile.set_preference("webdriver_enable_native_events", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.update_preferences()   
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

    site = browser.current_url
    browser.get('https://red3mp3.me/album/1276996/minas.html')
    songs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('player')
    print (site)

    for i in songs:
        print (i.get_attribute("data-title"))
        print (i.get_attribute("data-mp3url"))
        down = i.get_attribute("data-mp3url")
        browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
        browser.get("https://red3mp3.me" +down)
```

Comment: I tried your code, but used chrome and it started downloading all the mp3's.